# Show the abelianization of braid broup $B_n$,$n\geq 2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, braid-groups

I need to show that the abelianization of braid group $B_n$, for $n\geq2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, and that the commutator subgroup $[B_n,B_n]$ is exactly the set of braids represented by words with total exponent sum zero in the generators $\sigma_{i}$. I was able to show all generators $\sigma_i$ are conjugate to each other.

Here is the question:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that  all generators are conjugate (which you have shown) implies that all generators have the same image in $G/[G,G]$ (where $G=B_n$), so $G/[G,G]$ is cyclic and generated by any one of the generators.

On the other hand, the map $\phi$ sending every generator $\sigma_i$ to $1 \in {\mathbb Z}$ induces a surjective homomorphism, so $G/[G,G]$ is infinite, and hence infinite cyclic.

Note that $\ker \phi = [G,G]$ is the set of elements with total exponent sum $0$ in the generators.

Comment: Sorry, why all generators are conjugate to each other implies all generators have the same image in G/[G,G]? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Because $G/[G,G]$ is abelian, and two conjugate elements in an abelian group are equal.

Comment: Also, Now that I think more about it, I see why $ker(\phi)$ consists of elements with total exponent sum  0 in the generators but I still don't understand why $ker(\phi) =[G,G]$.

Comment: $G/K$  infinite cyclic implies $[G,G] \le K$, but  $G/[G,G]$ is cyclic, and all proper quotients of cyclic groups are finite, so $[G,G]=K$.