# Proving $B_n/[B_n,B_n]$ is infinite (cyclic) group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, braid-groups

Let $B_n$ be the braid group. I have shown that all generators of $B_n$ are conjugate, thereby proving that the surjective map $f:B_n \rightarrow B_n/[B_n,B_n]$ takes all generators of $B_n$ to a single generator, say $xH$ where $H$ is the commutator subgroup $[B_n,B_n]$ and $x$ is in $B_n$, which shows that $B_n/H$ is cyclic. Now, how do I prove that it is infinite? I think we'll have to use surjectivity of $f$ now, but how?

Comment: How is the braid group given to you? (I mean, if it is given via its standard presentation then the problem is not too hard!)

Comment: Hint: What is the order of a generator in $B_n$?

Comment: The order of a generator is infinite but we need to show here that it's abelianisation is infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the function $\ell$ from last time? It is defined by taking the number of positive exponents and subtracting the number of negative exponents. To show that the abelianization is infinite, it suffices to prove that $\sigma_1^n$ is not a product of commutators whenever $n > 1$. Note that every product of commutators $\beta \in [B_n, B_n]$ satisfies $\ell(\beta) = 0$. But $\ell(\sigma_1^n) = n$, which is non-zero. So $\sigma_1^n$ is not a product of commutators, whence the quotient has infinitely many elements.

Edit: As noted in the comments it is important to check that  $\ell$ is well-defined. This can be done by observing that applying the braid relations or commutativity relations does not change the value of $\ell$. From there it is also easy to see that the abelianization is infinite: Just check that $\ell$ is a homomorphism into an infinite abelian group.

Comment: But isn't the abelianisation l equal to fog where g is the surjective map : B_n --> B_n/[B_n,B_n] and f : B_n/[B_n,B_n] -> Z ? If not, how do you explicitly define l ?

Comment: I was taking a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2994078/show-the-abelianization-of-braid-broup-b-n-n-geq-2-is-isomorphic-to-mathbb but I didn't understand the infinite cyclic part.

Comment: You're right, that's what $\ell$ is, but here we don't need this. There is an explicit definition in my answer. We just need that it can check that the generarors are not products of commutators.

Comment: Really the main thing used here is that the length function is well-defined when described like this.

Comment: I had a small doubt, when you take the function l : B_n to Z, aren't you already assuming that the Abelianisation is isomorphic to Z ? Because l is what we get after we compose, unless you define it separately, which you have done here. I wanted to get there via the composition.

Comment: No, I am assuming nothing, I just define a map.

Comment: So we pause when we prove B_n/[B_n,B_n] is cyclic with one generator (as mentioned in the question) and then proceed to define l from B_n to Z separately (which later turns out to be the same as the composition map) and get that no generator raised to the power n can be in [B_n,B_n], hence B_n/[B_n,B_n] has to be infinite and hence isomorphic to Z.

Comment: Yes this works. I would say this is the most "geometric" way I know to see this. You could also just write down the abelian group presentation